# Spring Cloud Stream Kafka Custom Error Handler

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-kafka

I have Kafka Consumer using spring cloud stream

```yaml
spring:
  cloud:
    stream:
      function:
        definition: myConsumer
      bindings:
        myConsumer-in-0:
          destination:myDest
          binder: kafka
          group: myGroup
          content-type: application/json
```

I was able to catch errors through global error channel

```java
@ServiceActivator(inputChannel = IntegrationContextUtils.ERROR_CHANNEL_BEAN_NAME)
public void processError(Message<MessageHandlingException> message) {
  log.info("error had happend {}", message);
}
```

Now I have two questions

1. How can we redirect the error to a specific internal channel by a consumer?
2. Will the message be acknowledged automatically even for the error scenario?